# Magento 2 getExtensionAttributes return null

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.x

I am writing an Observer to `Magento\Customer\Account\Index` but the Objects from class `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` return null when getExtensionAttributes is executed.

```
  $customer = $customerFactory->create()->load($customerID); 
  //$customerRepository->get($customerID);
    $ext = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
    if($ext == null){
        throw new \Exception(" var ext = null");
    }
```

I used CustomerRepository and CustomerFactory to get $customer

Comment: Use repository instead of model class

Comment: I used CustomerRepository to get $customer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use CustomerFactory for getting customer data.

CustomerRepository is enough for getting a customer data.

You need to changes the code `if($ext == null){` to `if($ext === null){`.

```
//$customer = $customerFactory->create()->load($customerID); 
$customerRepository->get($customerID);
$ext = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
if($ext === null){
    throw new \Exception(" var ext = null");
}
```

`===` means **Identical** match condition which is vastly used at PHP 7,

See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` is not an Extensible Model (does not extend the `\Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject` class), it extending the `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` which is not an extensible object. You must use the repository, because it will return the instance of `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer` which is extensible object.

Or you can use your code, but with `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\CustomerFactory`.